# template recursion limitation (digest loop) in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angularjs-scope

I use recursive templates to render a tree in angularJS, but when tree depth is above 10, AngularJS gives me an error on the console saying:

```
"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Example in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eUG7E6wmn0QV94sPWpfN?p=preview).

If I understand correctly and try to put simple words on it (I know it's more complex):

- in the first $digest() iteration, it includes the first template and thus creates a ŵatcher over `item` (actually on `item.ID` and `item.children`
- then instead of including the template recursively and create watchers afterwards, it first wants to check item.children, and reruns the digest loop with `--ttl`
- then both values are the same, so it goes on and includes the next template and sets a watcher on the new `item`, and goes back to second step

Thus after 10 iterations, the ttl will be 0, hence the error, though there is no actual error...

So, a few questions:

- is my analysis correct?
- should I report this on the angular tracker (as I believe angular is wrong in reporting an error)?
- is there a simple workaround?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:**

[This plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/X1grV8MGBPErLJQ2p7ah?p=preview) (which you need to see with firefox because of a raw.github) shows that bindonce is not a solution to this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently a known issue of AngularJS, the only workarounds are not really satisfactory, See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6440).

Answer (score 1):

In a since deleted (why?) comment, someone has pointed me to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Fn8ujAx2OP4) where there is a workaround if the depth is known. [This plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eswdk9FW8E4Q3v426Oq4?p=preview) show it at work. This is not satisfactory, but it's one possible answer...